# How do I use the lock-keys-applet in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04. I used to have lock-keys-applet on the panel but since now I am using unity I see no way to get it back except that I use Ubuntu-classic. Somebody please tell me how can I get my lock-keys-applet back in Ubuntu 11.04 without using Ubuntu-classic.

P.S: Please excuse my bad English, I am learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to use Gnome panel applets in Unity. The only panel applets that work are indicator applets.

You can use another indicator applet called "Indicator-Keylock" To install it, type the following two commands into your terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock`

Then simply run the application and that should do it.

If you want a certain type of icon, you can install one of these three to match their respective themes:

`sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock-ubuntu-mono

sudo apt-get install  indicator-keylock-humanity

sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock-elementary`

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I was looking for, its even better than the applet I was using. I just wish that it gets included in the repositories.